# Launcher and Panel are gone

Tags: unity, launcher, panel

My Launcher and Panel are gone in Ubuntu 14.04.
I have already tried:

1. Update my software
2. Reinstall nvidia drivers
3. Play with confizconfig
4. Reset Unity

None of those worked, similar to other threads, the Guest account looks alright while mine does not.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either a corruption to Unity or a modification. Either way, following the below instructions should fix your problem.

Start by opening Terminal using (Ctrl+Alt+T) and then enter the below command.

`sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity && sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`

Doing this will reinstall both Unity and Ubuntu desktop essentially putting them back to default settings.

After the reinstall is complete, you will need to restart your computer for the changes to take affect.